# why does this `std::shared_ptr<>`managed object leak?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class test : public enable_shared_from_this<test> {
    vector<shared_ptr<test>> vec;
public:

    void addvec()
    {
        vec.emplace_back(shared_from_this());
    }
    ~test() { cout << "destructing\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    auto sp = make_shared<test>();

    sp->addvec(); // when called, destructor is not invoked and
                  // LeakSanitizer reports a memory leak
}
```

A `test` object is managed by `std::shared_ptr` and, after calling `addvec`, a second `shared_ptr` instance is stored in the internal vector (ref_count == 2).

But the destructor is never called and a memory leak is reported.
Why is this?

Compiled with `g++ -g -fsanitize=leak c.cpp`
GCC version 12.2.1

Comment: When is the second instance (of the shared pointer) supposed to be destroyed? (I see where the first instance, `sp` is destroyed, hence asking about the second.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shown code results in a circular reference. The object ends up containing a `shared_ptr` to itself.

A `shared_ptr`-referenced object gets automatically `delete`d only when the last `shared_ptr` to that object, itself, gets destroyed.

This never happens, in the shown code. Hence, the memory leak.

So-called "smart" pointers only work as long as there are no circular references, by definition.

With some careful planning, the services of a `std::weak_ptr` can be employed in order to deal with this situation.